# Creating dynamic static vars inside a class?

Tags: php, class, object, static-methods, static-variables

Is it possible to define dynamic vars or anyway to do the following?

Example 1:

```
class base
{
    protected static $$dynamicVar;

    protected function myFunction($value)
    {
        $dynamicVar = $value;
        self::$$dynamicVar = new $value();
    }
}
```

The idea behind this code is to instantiate new objects, without the base class knowing what objects will be instantiated.

I know instantiating new objects can be dynamic but I need it dynamic generated on static vars.

Thanks,

Comment: I know I can't do protected static $$var. Trying to illustrate what I need.

Comment: Someone please tell me a design pattern where such a construction would be needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as far as I know, but you can always do something like this:

```
class base
{
   protected static $dynProps = array();

   protected function myFunction($value)
   {
      self::$dynProps[$value] = new $value();
   }
}
```

The more important question here is **"Why do you need this?"**

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Arrays are usually slower then regular vars but it will probably work nice. Doing a system where all classes extends this base, and this base is responsible to load few other base classes that gonna be needed on all child classes, like a db class. Im trying to avoid the same class being instantiated twice if my system end having two instants of two classes extending base and needing db. So, it will check if $dynTempVar is not null, if not, it will instantiate the class as we mentioned above and then apply $this->$dyn = self::$$dynTempVar, so can use it with $this

Comment: As far I know the only way to do that is using static vars that will remain with its value even on different class if it was defined early. Appreciate if you got another way to do that.